# Convertir cualquier formato de fecha a una especifica

Tags: c#, android, date, xamarin, datetime

Estoy intentado trabajar unas operaciones con unas fechas, entonces lo que hago es tomar la fecha que la base de datos me devuelve en `string` y convertirla en una fecha con tipo estándar (`dd/MM/yyyy`), el problema es que según el dispositivo y configuración del cliente el formato de la fecha varia tanto al leerlas como al guardarlas y no tengo permitido cambiar el formato de las fechas ya guardadas.

En algunos es `dd-MM-yyyy` en otros es `MM-dd-yyyy` y para convertirla a una estándar utilizo este método:

```
DateTime TiempoFechaDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(TiempoFechaBD, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
```

Error:

> Error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Puedo hacer esto para que funcione sin importar con que formato venga el string?

Comment: Para esto debes conocer el formato original.

Comment: Si tienes 10/06/08... ¿es 10 de junio de 2008? ¿8 de junio de 2010? ¿6 de octubre de 2008?... en informática eso se conoce como GIGO (garbage in, garbage out). Si los datos que tienes son basura (de mala calidad), el resultado será basura.

Comment: Pudieras intentar TryParse https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-5.0

Comment: Hola, podrias decirme si la respuesta dada te fue util, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba poniendo esto:

```
Datetime fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(TiempoFechaBD, formato, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Para usar el **objeto CultureInfo** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Como no todas las PC usan el mismo formato para fechas como tú bien dices y para otros datos tales como monedas y decimales, es decir como desconoces el formato debes usar **CultureInfo.InvariantCulture**, digamos que es un "formato neutral".

Puedes investigar más sobre la **clase CultureInfo** en Internet.

Por cierto, para saber la cultura actual del sistema operativo puedes usar la instrucción:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name
```